# Long distance wifi for media cloud

Tags: wireless-networking, media-center

I'm wanting to set up a long distance wifi and put a media computer on it. I'd like to have two routers one that is my home network and then the second one would broadcast the long distance wifi, and the media pc would be on this router. How would I connect to this media pc through my home network. 
Would I beable to combine networks on my home router? the set up would look like this.

`{my computer}---- <home wifi-router>    <media wifi-router>----{media pc}`

could I make a custom dns setting in my home router to point to the media router and the corisponding IP address of the media pc?

Comment: I don't understand by what you mean by "long distance wifi"? DO you mean a long distance wireless network, or accessible over the interent? Pulling any sort of video over consumer wireless I would highly advise against but YMMV.

Comment: @tombull89 Basicly want to set-up a computer that people in the neiborhood could access but its not on my home network, is there a way to make it so they can access this from there own wireless network.

Comment: Skipping over the potential legal and security issues for a moment, you would have an unsecured wireless hotspot (or something like a Captive Portal that requires a login, with the username and password on the login page) with your media computer connected to it. You could connect your home computer on it but you would have to used a different subnet (or, if you really wanted to, buy a switch that supports VLANs).

Comment: DD-WRT or OpenWRT.

Comment: @Breakthrough OppenWRT i think, I plan on flashing a linksys wireless router and turning up the signal.

Comment: @tombull89 How would I make the computer or router (perferably) connect to that subnet when I want to access the media computer? Or are you saying I would have to disconnect from my home network and connect to the media computer network? I would like to avoid this.